# In which UK Transformers comic (maybe Machine Man) did a scientist commit suicide?

Tags: story-identification, comics, transformers

In the early 80's, I read the UK Transformers comic. There was a support comic as part of it, which in hindsight may have been Machine Man: the scene I remember was a character, who I think was a professor or engineering type, who committed suicide. I remember being quite upset by it (I would have been about 7 or 8); the character committed suicide by shooting themselves in the head. I think it was a revolver, and it was done 'off camera'. Sorry to be so vague!

Comment: Think it was this guy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_Man

Comment: This one; http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Back-up_strips#Machine_Man

Comment: I've been through Vol 1 and Vol 2 of Machine Man and I can't find any instances like you've described. The Transformers Comics featured a wide variety of "[Backup Strips](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Back-up_strips)". Perhaps you could narrow it down by identifying which one...

Comment: Thanks @Richard, but sorry - gave them away many years ago. No worries, was just something niggling at me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]issue 4 of the Machine Man mini series so i should think it was issue 41 or 42 of the UK Transformers comic

Comment: It's issue 42. The Machine Man back-up feature is a partial reprint of _Machine Man Vol. 2 #4_.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much (and thanks to everyone who contributed) :)

Answer (score 3):

It may have been [*2001 A Space Odyssey #8*](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_Vol_1_8), the first appearance of Machine Man (originally known as Mr. Machine, aka X-51). X-51's "father" Abel Stack (a scientist/robotics engineer) removes the explosive implanted in X-51, granting the robot his freedom from premature destruction by the government. After X-51 leaves, the explosive detonates, killing Abel.

[image: Abel Stack's death]

Comment: It doesn't ring a bell I'm afraid - I recall that the strip had a close up of the gun in his hand before the shot - but thank you